# Git find the head commit of all branches

Tags: git, git-branch

is there a possibility to get all branches of an git repository with thier head commit.

If I have the following repository:

```
* b562239 (HEAD -> master) lastCommit
* 3828834 (seccondBranch) seccond Commit 
| * 3f6fdf6 (firstBranch) branchCommit
|/  
* b051ccd init repo
```

I want to get a list like that:

```
master b562239
seccondBranch 3828834
firstBranch 3f6fdf6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plumbing tool for refs is [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(objectname:short)' refs/heads
```

for the exact output you wanted.

---

Also worth noting, `git branch -v` (or `-vv` for even slightly more verbose) will list all branches with the commit hash their tip points to, but in a much verbose way, since it also features info about remote branches association / last commit message.

Example output of a branch with `-v` :

```
development    f06f99b5c4 [behind 1] <commit message of commit f06f99b5c4>
```

Example output of a branch with `-vv` :

```
development    f06f99b5c4 [origin/development: behind 1] <commit message of commit f06f99b5c4>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works well. I didn't know `for-each-ref` before.

Comment: @Ahrtaler Yes, it's less used than its porcelain counterpart `git branch`

Comment: Worth noting it will list only local branches. If you want remote ones instead, replace `refs/heads` with `refs/remotes`.